# [ORACLE]How can I get the foreign key values using inline view?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, mybatis

What I'm trying to do is get the values using inline view.
on my table "mainBoard" has columns that tgno1,tgno2,tgno3, which are foreign keys refer the table,"Tag".
the table "Tag" has only two columns tgno(NUMBER), tgname(VARCHAR2).

I wanna return values from tgno(NUMBER) to tgname(VARCHAR2) using inline view.

here's what I tried for only one value:

```
SELECT tag1
FROM (SELECT tgname as tag1
FROM (SELECT tgname FROM tag WHERE tgno=1));
```

I wanna get all three values like:

```
SELECT tag1, tag2, tag3
FROM (SELECT...)
```

the final goal is to get the values of *tgname* values instead of *tgno1,2,3*  bellow:

```
    SELECT bno,bsubject,mno,bdate,bhit,bvote,tgno1,tgno2,tgno3,num
    FROM (SELECT bno,bsubject,mno,bdate,bhit,bvote,tgno1,tgno2,tgno3,rownum as num
    FROM (SELECT bno,bsubject,mno,bdate,bhit,bvote,tgno1,tgno2,tgno3
    FROM mainBoard WHERE btno=1 ORDER BY bno DESC ))
    WHERE num BETWEEN #{start} AND #{end}
```

Hope my question is understandable. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not join the the mainboard to tag 3 times, once for each column?

Comment: thanks, there were easy way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join mainboard to tag thrice once for each foreign key relationship to tag in mainboard.  Why do you have to have an inline view or was that just your approach?

```
SELECT MB.*, T1.tgName as Tag1Name, T2.tgName as Tag1Name, T3.tgName as Tag1Name
FROM mainboard MB
LEFT JOIN tag t1
 on T1.tgno = mb.tgno1
LEFT JOIN tag t2
 on T2.tgno2 = mb.tgno1
LEFT JOIN tag t3
 on T3.tgno3 = mb.tgno1
WHERE MB.num BETWEEN #{start} AND #{end}
```

I used left joins as I don't know if all 3 tag fields in MainBoard are always populated and assumed you wanted all mainboards regardless if tagno is populated in all 3.

Comment: It was just my approach. Thank you so much! those three tag fields have default value "none" for when there's no value populated.